# Combine two cursors (merge?), by keeping all distinct IDs from both cursors

Tags: android, merge, android-cursor

Say I have two cursors(called A and B). A and B has some columns identical, but the only true relation between the two is a single column, call it specialID. Cursor A is filled via a ContentProvider, whereas B contains all distinct IDs from a database of mine.

Is it possible to somehow merge the two cursor in a way that, 
Example A:

if A contains specialID 1,2,3,4,5
and B contains specialID 3,5,6,8
the result would be:
1,2,3,4,5,6,8
(keep all uniqe specialIDs from both cursors that is)

Example B:

if A contains no rows
and B contains specialID 4,5,6
the result would be:
4,5,6

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you specifically want a `Cursor` implementation that merges two Cursors in the way that you ask, there is a class called [`CursorJoiner`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorJoiner.html) though which does exactly what you want, but it's not a Cursor implementation.